# Ricci flow on Riemannian submersions

Tags: riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

Let $(P,g) \to (S^2,h)$ be a Riemannian submersion. Let $g(t)$ be the Ricci flow on $P$ with initial condition $g$. Does the induced flow on $S^2$ converges to the round metric on $S^2?$ I could conclude that this is true when we assume that the fibers are totally geodesic, but I have no idea to the approach on the general case.

I am trying to answer this question, or possibly, trying to understand how the flow evolves on the quotient. Are there papers exploiting questions like Ricci flow on Riemannian submersions?

One can assume, if necessary, that $P$ is a principal $SO(3)$--bundle, but I am not sure how this would helps.